# Generalized linear mixed models in SPSS specifying random effect: must I "add block" for my random factor (subject ID)?

Tags: repeated-measures, random-variable, spss, glmm

I'm trying to conduct a GLMM in SPSS with a DV that is ordinal (multinomial logistic regression as dist. and link function). I've encountered two issues:

1. It seems like in SPSS it is not possible to have a REPEATED statement if the DV is non-scalar. My DV is a repeated measure (pre- and post-treatment for each subject). Any suggestions? So far, I've 'solved' this dilemma by calculated a "change" measure (Post-treatment measure minus Pre-treatment measure), which seems fine in theory (e.g. I fundamentally care about the absolute magnitude of change in this variable so I don't really care that there are multiple ways the same "change" score can arise).
2. I'm unclear on how Subject_ID should be specified. One of my covariate variables is measured multiple times (3 brain regions within the same subject). I don't think this fact demands a REPEATED statement (but I might be wrong) -- instead it seems more like a covariate nested within Subject_ID. Not sure how to do this in a GLMM. So far I've simply represented those 3 covariate values as 3 separate rows in the data structure with a column (factor) for BrainRegion. I *think* so long as I have SubjectID as a Random factor this is okay (it seems to be working fine). What I also am unsure of is if I must "add Block to add Random Effect" Random Effects Blocks or if it is sufficient to simply add my Subject_ID variable in the Data Structure tab at the beginning. I guess I'm unclear on what this additional Add Block in the Fields/Effects tab (Random Effects) is doing. I'm not interested in estimating the random effects, I just need the model to understand that each subject has 3 rows, so I think I'm okay without adding a block for random effects...?